# Unable to open a SharePoint Application Page after deploying wsp

Tags: application-pages, farm-solution

I have created a SharePoint project which contains Application Pages and deployed it on Production server.

In Manage Farm Solution under Central Administration, this wsp show status as deployed.

When I try to navigate to the URL
http://c1:43616/_layouts/15/WPR/abc.aspx,
I get this error message-

[image]

How can I browse my published solution?

Comment: The application page is showing this error, please use the correlation ID to get the actual error message. Use [SharePoint ULS Logs Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to get the details

Comment: Please close the question by posting the answer